# how to delete duplicate values in a cell array of characters

Tags: matlab, char, duplicates

I have this `cell` array of `char`s:

```
a={'1';'1';'1';'1';'1';'3';'3';'3';'3';'3';'3';'4';'4';'4';'4'};
```

and I want to transform it into this:

```
a={'1';'';'';'';'';'3';'';'';'';'';'';'4';'';'';''};
```

Comment: Can you explain why? What are you planning on doing with the result? It seems fairly unnecessary and non-trivial

Comment: Are they always going to be numeric? Does the result have to be a cell array of characters?

Comment: Are duplicates always going to be grouped together?  And, if you have `a = {'1','1','2','2','1','1'}`  do you delete three "1"s or just the followers in each group?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, find the unique elements of `a` and their first indices. Then set all other entries of `a` to `''`.

```
[~, ii] = unique(a);
ind = setdiff(1:numel(a), ii);
[a{ind}] = deal('');
```

As pointed out by CST-Link, both the computation of duplicate indices and assignment of empty strings can be sped up (in particular, `setdiff` is slow):

```
[~, ii] = unique(a);
ind = 1:numel(a);
ind(ii) = [];
a(ind) = {''};
```

Comment: You could go faster with `[~, ii] = unique(a); ind = 1:numel(a); ind(ii) = []; a(ind) = {''};`

Comment: This is close to what `rle` would do, interestingly (or not :-) )

Answer (score 5):

This could be fast for large arrays:

```
a=repmat({'1';'1';'1';'1';'1';'3';'3';'3';'3';'3';'3';'4';'4';'4';'4'}, 100000, 1);

[u,n] = unique(flipud(a));
b = repmat({''}, size(a));
b(n) = u;
a = flipud(b);
```

Comment: `repmat` is typically known for its *lack* of speed. Do you have any evidence that this pays off for large arrays?:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak `repmat` is O(1) though it has a large overhead, while `unique` is O(n*log(n)). I changed the code for a large array `a` so you can profile it yourself. Try smaller or larger values for the number of duplicates in the definition of `a`; please let me know if you got different complexities.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Just checked the code that I proposed against the original one that was chosen as answer. For 100000 (one hundred thousands) copies of the original `a` my code ran in 0.9 seconds, while the other ran in 1.4 seconds (MATLAB R2012a, i5, 3Gb RAM). I hope that this is evidence enough. :-)

Comment: Of course it's enough, thank you:) I was only curious, and didn't know which one would come out on top.

Comment: Indeed, for large arrays (tested with 3e5 elements) this solution is faster than my originally proposed one. For smaller ones (tested with 30 elements), it is the slowest. Your improvement to my originally proposed solution is fastest, in all tested cases. Interestingly, for large arrays, `deal` is the bottleneck...